# How to push only a subset of committed files?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, push, dvcs

We recently switched from svn to mercurial. We're using Aptana as our IDE with the MercurialEclipse plugin, along with BitBucket for our repositories and SourceTree as our (additional) source control GUI.

I created 2 new files in Aptana, and committed each of them. Now in the Synchronize view, where the 2 files are listed as "outgoing", I'd like to push **only one of them**. I avoided using the "push all" icon at the top which would push all outgoing changes - instead I right-clicked a specific file in the outgoing list and chose "push" from the context menu. However, this caused **both** outgoing changes to be pushed. I can't seem to find any option to push only a specific file or subset of files of the committed changes. Is there any way to accomplish this in Aptana?

Answer (score 1):

Note: My answer doesn't relate to Aptana, but instead covers what I think your issue is.

I think the main problem is a misunderstanding of how Mercurial stores its changes, which coming from a Subversion background is perfectly reasonable.

In Subversion, change history can be considered to be stored per file.  That is, if you change two files and commit them, you can easily, and often do, have a situation where files in your working copy are at different versions.

In Mercurial, change history is stored across the whole repository.  Committing will create a new "Changeset", which stores the state of the entire repository at that time.  When you decide to `push` a change out to another repository, all modifications (or adds, or deletes, or...) will be pushed out with that change.

A caveat is that when you decide to `commit` a new changeset to your repository, you can selectively include or exclude files.  Files not included will remain in your working copy as pending modifications, which can be committed in a new changeset.

I hope that makes sense to you - if you already understand it, it's a logical concept, but I find it tricky to explain.

So, on to your problem.

Lets say you have two files in your repository, `file1` and `file2` (it's that or `foo` and `bar`).  You've changed them both, but they relate to different issues - they can be committed as different changesets:

```
$ hg log
changeset 0:....
summary:   First commit

$ hg st
M file1
M file2

$ hg commit -I file1 -m "Changed file1"

$ hg log
changeset 1:....
summary:   Changed file1

changeset 0:....
summary:   First commit

$ hg st
M file2
```

Here you can see that we've committed only one file into the repository, and it's made a new changeset with the complete state of the repository at that time, *minus* the changes to `file2`.  We can now do the same, committing `file2`, which will create another changeset.  The problem with this approach is that changesets are ordered according to their parent, and so you couldn't easily `push` just the change to `file2`, without also pushing its parent - but it may be closer to what you're after.

---

TL;DR : SVN stores the state of individual files, Mercurial stores the state of the repository as a whole.

I very much recommend reading [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/).  It's a little out-of-date in places, but I think it will do a much better job of getting the concept across.